# How to use AWS ECR login with aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I want to pull from a private AWS ECR. I have created a new policy and a API user with the correct permissions to pull.

The issue I have is... I'm running this on a machine where I don't want to use credentials files:

```
aws ecr get-login
```

I would like to use the `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` to get a login token i.e

```
aws ecr get-login <aws_access_key_id> <aws_secret_access_key>
```

Is this possible or do I have any way to achieve this without saving out a file or running `aws configure`?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify your configuration with environment variables, for example like this (Linux/Mac OS):

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
```

They will then only last until the end of your shell session (unless you put them in your shell startup script). You can read more about this, and see additional examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html#envvars-set).

Comment: Seemed like it would work, but it does not with `aws ecr get-login`

Comment: You can check that the credentials have actually been set with the ```aws configure list``` command. Does it display the right credentials? What kind of error message do you get?